# Variable Missing with no defaults

Tags: r, function

Hello I have a sample data set that I am trying to create a function to find wind chill for.This is the set:

```
       HighTemp WindSpeed Snowfall
1-Jan        19         8      0.0
2-Jan
3-Jan        25         9      0.0
4-Jan        33        14      7.6
5-Jan        38         7      0.0
6-Jan        34         6      2.1
7-Jan        35        12      0.0
8-Jan        27        15      0.0
9-Jan        28        11      3.3
10-Jan       30        17      1.4
11-Jan       36        13      0.0
12-Jan       44         9      0.0
13-Jan       41         8      0.0
14-Jan       34        14      0.0
15-Jan       31        15      0.0
16-Jan       32        12      2.8
17-Jan       35        18      0.0
18-Jan       20        22      0.0
19-Jan       17        24      0.0
20-Jan       16        20      0.6
21-Jan       19         8      0.0
22-Jan       25         9      0.0
23-Jan       28        13     14.9
24-Jan       23        11      0.0
25-Jan       28        32      0.0
26-Jan       33        13      0.0
27-Jan       31        15      3.7
28-Jan       39        10      0.0
29-Jan       36         4      0.0
30-Jan       33         8      0.9
31-Jan       37        10      0.0
```

I am trying to create a function that executes this equation for each date of the month:

Wind Chill= 35.74+0.6215Ta-35.75v^0.16+0.4275TaV^0.16
Where Ta= HighTemp and V= WindSpeed

The code I've written is:

```
wind_chill<-function(HighTemp,WindSpeed){
twc<-(35.74)+(0.6215)*(HighTemp)-(35.75)*(WindSpeed)^0.16+(0.4275)*(HighTemp*WindSpeed)^0.16
return(twc)
}

wind_chill(jan_weather)
```

But it returns an error reading WindSpeed is missing with no defaults.
Please help I'm very new to this and just cannot figure this out.

Comment: You define `wind_chill` with two arguments `wind_chill<-function(HighTemp,WindSpeed)` but pass only one value to it. `wind_chill(jan_weather)` hence you get an error. Try with `wind_chill(jan_weather$HighTemp, jan_weather$WindSpeed)`. If `jan_weather` is name of your dataframe.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

`wind_chill` function accepts two arguments but you have passed only one in your attempt. Try to pass the column values to the function.

```
result <- wind_chill(jan_weather$HighTemp, jan_weather$WindSpeed)
```

Another way would be to pass dataframe to the function and changing the function to :

```
wind_chill<-function(df){
  twc<- (35.74)+(0.6215)*(df$HighTemp) - (35.75)* (df$WindSpeed)^0.16+
        (0.4275)*(df$HighTemp*df$WindSpeed)^0.16
  return(twc)
}

result <- wind_chill(jan_weather)
```